# node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js:

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am new to react-native and expo based application. i made an application that was running very smooth initially until i import Audio from expo-av. The audio/sound doesn't work properly as after some clicks the sound stops working. And now if i tried to run my project, it didnt even open and gives me this error " error: node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously."
Even though i havnt made any major installation in my project.   i have tried both node v16.4.0 and also node v18.17.0(both gives me error). these are details of "dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.4",
"expo": "^49.0.6",
"expo-av": "^13.4.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.72.3",
"react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
},
THANX IN ADVANCE

before sound, the code is working but after sound the code runs only few times and after that giving me this error.
HERE IS THE CODE

```
    import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
    
    import { sound } from "../Home"; // like globalvariable

const GamePage = (props) => {
    
      const sou=new Audio.Sound()
    
      async function playSound(music) {
        try{
         if (sound){
        
          await sou.loadAsync(music)
          await sou.playAsync(); }
         
        }
          catch(e){"errrrrr", console.log(e)}
      }
    
       React.useEffect(() => {
        return sou ? () => { sou.unloadAsync(); }
          : undefined;
      }, [sou]);



     const ColorPress = (colour) => {
    
        if (colour === targetColor) {
          try {
         playSound(require('../../assets/click.wav'))}
         catch (e){console.log(e)}
          setScore(score + 1);
          shufflecolors()
          setTargetColor(getRandomColor())
        }
        else {
          playSound(require('../../assets/end.wav'))
          setPlay(false)
          clearInterval(interval.current);
          setModalVisible(true)
        }
      
      };


return (
ColorPress (color) method is being called by TouchableOpacity
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.